# React Native: Navigate and clear stack

Tags: react-native

I am trying to navigate (with animation) from a login page to the landing page, and then clear the navigation stack so the user can't go back to the login page.

The Navigator's `resetTo` method accomplishes this, except for the animation. This has to be very common request. Anyone know the right way to do this?

Comment: from login page to landing page, why not use replace so as not to add the login page to the stack?

Comment: I could, but the transition looks better. :)